# How do I rotate a box in A-Frame by moving or dragging the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aframe, webvr

How do I rotate a box in A-Frame by moving or dragging the mouse?

I trying to do something like this: 
http://codepen.io/jordizle/pen/haIdo/
https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/n6u6asza/

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rotation</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <a-image id="a" src="Background.jpg">
    </a-assets>
    <a-box id="b1" src="#a" position="2 2 -3"></a-box>
    <a-box id="b2" src="#a" position="-2 2 -3"></a-box>
    <a-camera position="0 0 0">
      <a-cursor></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
  </a-scene>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var box=document.querySelector('a-box');
    var isDragging=false;
    box.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
      isDragging=true;
    });
    box.addEventListener('mousemove',function(event) {
      if(isDragging)
      {
          box.setAttribute('rotation', {x:event.clientX , y:event.clientY, z:0});
      }
    });
    box.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      if(isDraggging)
      {
        isDragging=false;
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about register a new component to control drag rotate? first, you need to disable `look-controls`,because `look-controls` also use the drag operation. second, attach event listeners to document.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rotation</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    AFRAME.registerComponent('drag-rotate-component',{
      schema : { speed : {default:1}},
      init : function(){
        this.ifMouseDown = false;
        this.x_cord = 0;
        this.y_cord = 0;
        document.addEventListener('mousedown',this.OnDocumentMouseDown.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mouseup',this.OnDocumentMouseUp.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mousemove',this.OnDocumentMouseMove.bind(this));
      },
      OnDocumentMouseDown : function(event){
        this.ifMouseDown = true;
        this.x_cord = event.clientX;
        this.y_cord = event.clientY;
      },
      OnDocumentMouseUp : function(){
        this.ifMouseDown = false;
      },
      OnDocumentMouseMove : function(event)
      {
        if(this.ifMouseDown)
        {
          var temp_x = event.clientX-this.x_cord;
          var temp_y = event.clientY-this.y_cord;
          if(Math.abs(temp_y)<Math.abs(temp_x))
          {
            this.el.object3D.rotateY(temp_x*this.data.speed/1000);
          }
          else
          {
            this.el.object3D.rotateX(temp_y*this.data.speed/1000);
          }
          this.x_cord = event.clientX;
          this.y_cord = event.clientY;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  <a-scene>
    <a-box id="b1" color="green" position="2 2 -3" drag-rotate-component></a-box>
    <a-box id="b2" color="blue" position="-2 2 -3"></a-box>
    <a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled:false">
      <a-cursor></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
  </a-scene>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly!