# How do I rotate a 3d model in A-Frame by moving or dragging the mouse?

Tags: rotation, aframe, 3d-model

Based on this [How do I rotate a box in A-Frame by moving or dragging the mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041517/how-do-i-rotate-a-box-in-a-frame-by-moving-or-dragging-the-mouse/42105892#42105892)

how i can do it with a 3d model? i need rotate a 3d model/object in a view

i have tried this code, but doesn't works

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rotation</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    AFRAME.registerComponent('drag-rotate-component',{
      schema : { speed : {default:1}},
      init : function(){
        this.ifMouseDown = false;
        this.x_cord = 0;
        this.y_cord = 0;
        document.addEventListener('mousedown',this.OnDocumentMouseDown.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mouseup',this.OnDocumentMouseUp.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mousemove',this.OnDocumentMouseMove.bind(this));
      },
      OnDocumentMouseDown : function(event){
        this.ifMouseDown = true;
        this.x_cord = event.clientX;
        this.y_cord = event.clientY;
      },
      OnDocumentMouseUp : function(){
        this.ifMouseDown = false;
      },
      OnDocumentMouseMove : function(event)
      {
        if(this.ifMouseDown)
        {
          var temp_x = event.clientX-this.x_cord;
          var temp_y = event.clientY-this.y_cord;
          if(Math.abs(temp_y)<Math.abs(temp_x))
          {
            this.el.object3D.rotateY(temp_x*this.data.speed/1000);
          }
          else
          {
            this.el.object3D.rotateX(temp_y*this.data.speed/1000);
          }
          this.x_cord = event.clientX;
          this.y_cord = event.clientY;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  <a-scene>
   <a-assets>
      <a-asset-item id="man" src="./assets/models/man/man.dae"></a-asset-item>
   </a-assets>
   <a-collada-model src="#man" rotation="0 45 0"></a-model>
   <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
   <a-entity position="0 -0.5 1">
     <a-camera look-controls="enabled:false"></a-camera>
   </a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Also have tried this, but not luck

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title - Demo 3D Model</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Inlabs demo - 3D Model">
        <script src="../../../dist/aframe-master.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="man" src="./assets/models/man/man.dae"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>

      <a-collada-model src="#man" rotation="0 45 0"></a-model>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
      <a-entity position="0 -0.5 1">
        <a-camera drag-rotate-component look-controls="enabled:false"></a-camera>
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the `drag-rotate-component` to the model not the camera.

`<a-collada-model drag-rotate-component>`

Also, you don't need to add `-component` to the component name.

Comment: Thanks for help!! now its working, https://codepen.io/djcesar/pen/EmwKQV

By the same topic is there any way to change the center of rotation axis? this to rotate the model like the example with axis on the center https://sketchfab.com/models/e44c452648ab42d2bd5b87ff2f5937b5 , not with axis on the corner of the model as the codepen

Comment: This component is somehow not working at Version 0.9.0. Has anybody a solution?

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: sorry, my bad, this is not correct as it doesn't answer the question.*

I think you simply forgot to append the name of the component `drag-rotate-component` as an attribute to the camera entity. See this [pen](https://codepen.io/deva/pen/dWVPyr).

```
<a-camera drag-rotate-component look-controls="enabled:false"></a-camera>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, it does not works for my case, works as the pen but the desired function is rotate the model, not the current view.

i need do something like this https://sketchfab.com/models/e44c452648ab42d2bd5b87ff2f5937b5