# How do you use jquery to change position of object in aframe?

Tags: jquery, aframe

I am trying to move an a-frame sphere using jquery attr().

I used this in the script tag(the a-sphere is already there with the id sphere.):

```
  var x = '0 5 0';
  $("#sphere").attr('position', x);
```

It doesn't work. Is there a different way to change it or do I have a mistake?

Comment: You can maybe find something here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041517/how-do-i-rotate-a-box-in-a-frame-by-moving-or-dragging-the-mouse

Comment: It is about rotating with drag, but this is changing the position/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setAttribute`. More info in [A-Frame docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#adding-a-component-with-setattribute)

```
$("#sphere")[0].setAttribute('position', {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3});
```

FYI, you can also use the standard DOM querySelector instead of jQuery

```
document.querySelector(“#sphere”).setAttribute('position', {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3});
```

If still doesn’t work I recommend sharing code that people can run and debug. [Glitch is great](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe)

Comment: The second answer works but the first doesn't. Thanks!